# Split file in arbitrary N byte slices

Tags: rust

I need to divide a file into N byte segments. Currently, I am using a code that splits the file into segments of a fixed size (`LEN`). However, I need to use a calculated value instead of `LEN`. The issue is that `let mut slice_buffer = [0u8; LEN];` can only use a constant value for `LEN`, and I cannot use a variable.

Is there an alternative way to push arbitrary length vector chunks to `file_slices: Vec<Vec<u8>>`, so that `file_slices.len() < 255` regardless of the size of the file?

```
    let mut file = match File::open(path).unwrap();
    const LEN: usize = 4096;
    let mut file_slices: Vec<Vec<u8>> = Vec::new();
    let mut slice_buffer = [0u8; LEN];
    let mut bytes_in_last_row = 0;

    //slice the file into 4096 byte slices
    let mut end_of_file = false;
    while !end_of_file {
        let bytes_read = file.read(&mut slice_buffer).unwrap();

        if bytes_read != 0 {
            let mut slice_vec: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
            bytes_in_last_row = bytes_read;
            for i in 0..LEN {
                slice_vec.push(slice_buffer[i]);
            }

            file_slices.push(slice_vec);
            slice_buffer = [0u8; LEN];
        } else {
            end_of_file = true;
        }
    }
    println!("Vector size is {} lines.", file_slices.len());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you read into an array then copy this array into a vector, I suggest you directly read into a vector (length is adjustable, not a constant, as you requested).

Note that avoiding copies is done by swapping with a new vector (ready for the next chunk).

I tried to stay as close as possible to your original example.

In your own answer, you gave details about the last chunk; I adjusted accordingly.

Be aware that nothing guaranties that `read()` will return exactly `chunk_length` if it's not `0` (it can be less than the requested amount), even in the middle of the file (not necessarily at the end).
The [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#tymethod.read) states

> It is not an error if the returned value n is smaller than the buffer size, even when the reader is not at the end of the stream yet. This may happen for example because fewer bytes are actually available right now (e. g. being close to end-of-file) or because read() was interrupted by a signal.

```rust
use std::io::Read;

fn make_file_slices(
    path: &str,
    chunk_length: usize,
) -> Result<Vec<Vec<u8>>, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let mut file = std::fs::File::open(path)?;
    let mut file_slices = Vec::new();
    let mut slice_buffer = vec![0_u8; chunk_length];
    let mut bytes_in_last_row = 0;
    loop {
        // read (may-be) incomplete chunk
        let bytes_read = file.read(&mut slice_buffer[bytes_in_last_row..])?;
        if bytes_read == 0 {
            // EOF
            if bytes_in_last_row > 0 {
                // keep the incomplete (zero padded) last chunk
                file_slices.push(slice_buffer);
            }
            break;
        }
        bytes_in_last_row += bytes_read;
        if bytes_in_last_row == chunk_length {
            // the current chunk is complete
            bytes_in_last_row = 0;
            let mut tmp = vec![0_u8; chunk_length];
            std::mem::swap(&mut tmp, &mut slice_buffer);
            file_slices.push(tmp);
        }
    }
    Ok(file_slices)
}

fn main() {
    match make_file_slices("src/main.rs", 12) {
        Ok(file_slices) => {
            println!("Vector size is {} lines.", file_slices.len());
            for (i, s) in file_slices.iter().enumerate() {
                println!("{}: {:?}", i, s);
            }
        }
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Error: {:?}", e);
        }
    }
}
/*
Vector size is 112 lines.
0: [117, 115, 101, 32, 115, 116, 100, 58, 58, 105, 111, 58]
1: [58, 82, 101, 97, 100, 59, 10, 10, 102, 110, 32, 109]
2: [97, 107, 101, 95, 102, 105, 108, 101, 95, 115, 108, 105]
...
109: [114, 58, 32, 123, 58, 63, 125, 34, 44, 32, 101, 41]
110: [59, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 125, 10]
111: [32, 32, 32, 32, 125, 10, 125, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0]
*/
```

Comment: I use this code to implement the data recovery Reed-Solomon Galois field (2^8) algorithm. I need to convert the file to a vector of maximum 256 equal length vectors (shards) of N bytes.

Answer (score 2):

```
let mut file = Vec::new();
File::open("foo").unwrap().read_to_end(&mut file);
let file_slices: Vec<&[u8]> = file.chunks(256).collect();
```

Here `file_slices` is a collection of references to `file`. This saves copying the entire file again but means you can't drop `file` for as long as `file_slices` lives.

If you want a deep copy, you can do this instead:

```
let file_slices: Vec<Vec<u8>> = {
    let mut file = Vec::new();
    File::open("foo").unwrap().read_to_end(&mut file);

    file.chunks(256).map(<[u8]>::to_vec).collect()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `Vec`: `let slice_buffer = vec![0; LEN]`, then [`truncate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.truncate) it to the right size and put that directly in your output:

```
let mut file = match File::open(path).unwrap();
const LEN: usize = 4096;
let mut file_slices: Vec<Vec<u8>> = Vec::new();
let mut bytes_in_last_row = 0;

//slice the file into 4096 byte slices
let mut end_of_file = false;
while !end_of_file {
    let mut slice = vec![0; LEN];
    let bytes_read = file.read(&mut slice[..]).unwrap();

    if bytes_read != 0 {
        slice.truncate (bytes_read);
        file_slices.push(slice);
    } else {
        end_of_file = true;
    }
}
println!("Vector size is {} lines.", file_slices.len());
```

Answer (score 0):

@prog-fh solution almost solved my problem. Since it helped me do it I marked it as "Accepted".
My code adds zeros if the length of the last chunk is less than `chunk_length`, so I removed `chunk_count` at all and simplified the loop in this way:

```
loop {
        // read (may-be) incomplete chunk
        let bytes_read = file.read(&mut slice_buffer[bytes_in_last_row..])?;
        if bytes_read == 0 {
            break; // EOF
        }

        // the current chunk is complete
        bytes_in_last_row = 0;
        let mut tmp = vec![0_u8; chunk_length];
        std::mem::swap(&mut tmp, &mut slice_buffer);
        file_slices.push(tmp);
    }
```

Comment: In what is shown here, it seems that you removed the update of bytes_in_last_row with bytes_read and the test of bytes_in_last_row. Nothing guaranties that `read()` will return exactly `chunk_length` if it's not 0, **even in the middle of the file** (not necessarily at the end). If you need the incomplete last chunk, you just have to push it before the break if bytes_in_last_row is greater than zero.

Comment: I adjusted my answer according to these new elements. I guess that `file_slices.len() < 255` was no longer needed.